# What is the code to select which database table the php page has to show?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a code that permits the user to show any table in my database in a php page.

I tried with that code:

```
<?php
include('connection_db.php'); 
$table = $_POST['table'];

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM $table";
$sql2 = "SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '$table'";
$sql3 = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'$table'";

$result = mysql_query($sql1);
$column = mysql_query($sql2);
$ncolumn= mysql_query($sql3);

echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $column; $i++) {
        echo "<td>". $row['$ncolumn'] ."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";     

    echo "<br/>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

It should show the entire table with his records, but it shows only a lot of empty lines

Comment: The old mysql extension (the `mysql_...()` functions) is deprecatred and does not exist any more in current versions of the php language. Please use the newer mysqli extension instead.

Comment: Using values sent by the client directly in sql queries is a huge security risk. You can never trust anything the client has specified. Please read and learn about the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: You don't need to query the information schema, actually. The first query selecting all entries in a database actually also holds the column names as element keys. That is all the information you need to render the table including a header row.

Comment: And be careful to blindly select all entries in a table. What if the table contains 200 billion records? You really want to load them all at the same time? Not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = $_POST['table'];
$mysqli  =  new mysqli(_DB_SERVER_,_DB_USER_,_DB_PASSWD_,_DB_NAME_);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $Message =  "Connect failed: %s\n" . $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'")) {
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $Tableexists = "yes";
        } else {
        $Tableexists = "no";
    }
    } else {
    $Tableexists = 0;
}

echo $Tableexists;
```

Comment: It gives me "0" in every table